# Query random item per day in android sql

Tags: android, sqlite, random

I am developing a mobile application that has thousands of records in a table and **has a word of the day feature**. The problem is that sqlite does not support seeding random function like mysql does in this sample query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM word_table 
 ORDER BY RAND('. date("mdY") .') LIMIT 1
```

Here is the code Im using

**EntriesDataSource.java**

```
public void insertWordForTheDayInfo(){
    String insert_columnd_id = "INSERT INTO " + EntriesDBOpenHelper.TABLE_WORD_OF_THE_DAY_TRACKER + "("+ EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID + ") VALUES (1)";
    database.execSQL(insert_columnd_id);

    //get the current date first
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    String date = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    //get the entry id first
    String entry_id = "SELECT * FROM " + EntriesDBOpenHelper.TABLE_ENTRIES + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
    Cursor oldCursor = database.rawQuery(entry_id, null); 
    oldCursor.moveToFirst();

    int id = oldCursor.getInt(oldCursor.getColumnIndex(EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID));

    String insert_data = "UPDATE " + EntriesDBOpenHelper.TABLE_WORD_OF_THE_DAY_TRACKER + " SET " + 
                        EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_CURRENT_DATE + " ='" + date + "', " + EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ENTRY_ID + "= " + id + " WHERE " + EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = 1"; 

    database.execSQL(insert_data);
}


public int retrieveWordForTheDayInfo(){
    //get the current date first
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    String date = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    //String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + EntriesDBOpenHelper.TABLE_WORD_OF_THE_DAY_TRACKER + " WHERE " + EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_CURRENT_DATE + " = '" + date + "'";
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + EntriesDBOpenHelper.TABLE_WORD_OF_THE_DAY_TRACKER + " WHERE " + EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = 1";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ENTRY_ID));

    return id;
}


public Entry wordForTheDay(){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + EntriesDBOpenHelper.TABLE_ENTRIES + " WHERE " + EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + 1;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

    Entry entry = new Entry();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            entry.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID)));
            entry.setWord(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_WORD)));
            entry.setAudioUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_AUDIO_URL)));
            entry.setCategory(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_CATEGORY)));
            entry.setSubCategory(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_SUBCATEGORY)));
            entry.setMeaning(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EntriesDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_MEANING)));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.i(LOGTAG, "wordForTheDay(). Total entry: " + cursor.getCount() + " rows");
    return entry;
}
```

**WordOfTheDayFragment.java (onCreate)**

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    listener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            changeLayout();
        }
    };

    settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

    datasource = new EntriesDataSource(getActivity());
    datasource.open();

    //insert date and id
    datasource.insertWordForTheDayInfo();

    //retrieve entry id
    int entry_id = datasource.retrieveWordForTheDayInfo();

    //retrieve entry info
    entry = datasource.wordForTheDay(entry_id);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider having the word_table have to fields, an ID (1,2, ... n) and the word.  Then compute the random id in your app and use:

```
SELECT word
  FROM word_table
 WHERE id=<random id>
```

If you are using Java for the app you can generate the randomId using code like

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int RandomId = randomGenerator.nextInt(numRecords);
```

Where you have obtained the number of records (numRecords) using a query like:

```
SELECT count(1)
  FROM word_table
```

For the long run, I would also suggest that you create SQL functions to call for your operations with your database.  That way you can adjust the table structures as you need, without having to recode your application.

If you want to establish a new "random" item for each day, you might create a separate table (one row) that contains a timestamp and the random id.  You could create a function that you pass the random_id to -- it would use the currently stored random id if the date is still in the same day, or the new random_id and overwrite the date, id in the special table

Comment: Thanks @ErstwhileIII for your reply, how can I compute the random id in application? Sorry for being noob

Comment: I have expanded the answer.

Comment: I have integrated your code with mine, but what I want is to query 1 item per day regardless how many times you refresh the app it will only display the same item the whole day. I would like to upvote your answer but I got less than 15 reputation.

Comment: you should be able to "accept" the answer.  I will edit to add a way to get the same each time for 24 hours.

Comment: but not one that returns the same random number a day at a time.

Comment: Hello @ErstwhileIII, Thanks for your suggestion, I now get the logic but still having a problem. But Im still struggling to generate random ID once. Because it still generates random id everytime I refresh my fragment. I have updated my question along with my code above.

Comment: You might put the randomID and the time it was last created into local app storage (savme two key/value pairs) ... logic would be to get randomIDCreatedTime and if less than 24 hours ago, get the randomID.  If not, generate a new randomID and store that value and the createtime locally in the pairs storage